# Laravel - Scope - Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I have a model called "Consol", where I have a scope that looks like this:

```
public function scopeOfFinalsSent($query, $set)
{
    if ($set) {

        return $query->whereNotNull('finals_sent')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('final_weight', '>=', 'current_weight')
                ->where('final_cbm', '>=', 'current_cbm');
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

I am using it like this:

```php
return Consol::ofFinalsSent(true)->count();
```

When using this scope together with MSSQL, I get the below error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [consols] where [first_etd] between 2020-04-20 and 2020-04-26 and [finals_sent] is not null and ([final_weight] >= current_weight and [final_cbm] >= current_cbm))

Please note, if I switch over to MySQL, I don't get the above error.

I have tried to debug the actual query, by using the `toSql()` method, on my scope. The query, that I am performing looks like this:

```sql
select * from [consols] where [first_etd] between '2020-04-20' and '2020-04-26' and [finals_sent] is not null and ([final_weight] >= "current_weight" and [final_cbm] >= "current_cbm")
```

When running this query directly in the SQL Server Management Studio on the actual table, the query is being executed perfectly.

Below you can see the schema for the table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `whereColumn` to compare values of columns, in your case:

```php
public function scopeOfFinalsSent($query, $set)
{
    if ($set) {

        return $query->whereNotNull('finals_sent')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereColumn('final_weight', '>=', 'current_weight')
                ->whereColumn('final_cbm', '>=', 'current_cbm');
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Otherwise you end up comparing things like `final_weight` to the string value `"current_weight"`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by using the `whereRaw` method that Laravel provides, as I suspected something "going on behind the scenes" with the `where` method.

My scope now looks like this (notice the `whereRaw` instead of `where` being used):

```php
public function scopeOfFinalsSent($query, $set)
{
    if ($set) {

        return $query->whereNotNull('finals_sent')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereRaw('final_weight >= current_weight')
                ->whereRaw('final_cbm >= current_cbm');
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds

Comment: I still like your answer more, since you are using the `whereColumn`, thus making it more explicit in my eyes.